# The current request is not a multipart request on MockMultipartFile test

Tags: spring, multipart, mockmvc

I too am posting about the dreaded "The current request is not a multipart request" message.

I'm using the latest of Spring and siblings and have the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.....project.rest" })
@Import({JsonConfiguration.class})
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver =  new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(1024000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
}
```

I also have a controller handler:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.BTS)
public class BTSUploadController {

        @RequestMapping(value = RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.UPLOAD, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        @ResponseBody
        public String handleFileUpload(@RequestPart(value = "json") JsonPojo pojo, @RequestParam(value = "random") String random, @RequestParam(value = "data", required = false) List<MultipartFile> uploadedFiles, BindingResult result) {
    }
}
```

With the constants:

```
public static final String SLASH = "/";
public static final String BTS = "bts";
public static final String UPLOAD = "upload";
```

And finally the test:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).addFilters(this.springSecurityFilterChain).build();
}

@Before
public void beforeAnyTest() throws Exception {
    httpHeaders = Common.createAuthenticationHeaders("stephane" + ":" + PASSWORD);
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    MockMultipartFile firstFile = new MockMultipartFile("data", "filename.txt", "text/plain", "some xml".getBytes());
    MockMultipartFile secondFile = new MockMultipartFile("data", "other-file-name.data", "text/plain", "some other type".getBytes());
    MockMultipartFile jsonFile = new MockMultipartFile("json", "", "application/json", "{\"json\": \"someValue\"}".getBytes());

    MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(
            fileUpload(RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.BTS + RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.UPLOAD)
            .file(firstFile)
            .file(secondFile)
            .file(jsonFile)
            .headers(httpHeaders)
            .param("random", "4")
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string("success"))
            .andReturn();
    String value = deserialize(mvcResult, String.class);
    assertEquals(value, "success");
```

}

But the Maven build gives me the following message:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request
```

Any clue ?

I've been googling for a good hour now...

EDIT: The full stacktrace

```
2014-09-26 18:52:13,163 ERROR  [ExceptionsHandler] There was an RTE error. 
2014-09-26 18:52:13,182 DEBUG  [ExceptionsHandler] org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.assertIsMultipartRequest(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:170)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:137)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:145)
    at com.nsn.nitro.project.rest.controller.BTSUploadControllerTest.test(BTSUploadControllerTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
```

EDIT: some more configuration

```
public class WebInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebInit.class);

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        registerListener(servletContext);

        registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);

        registerJspServlet(servletContext);
    }

    private void registerListener(ServletContext servletContext) {
        // Create the root application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = createContext(ApplicationConfiguration.class, WebSecurityConfiguration.class);

        // Set the application display name
        appContext.setDisplayName("NI");

        // Create the Spring Container shared by all servlets and filters
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appContext));
    }

    private void registerDispatcherServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = createContext(WebConfiguration.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webApplicationContext));
        dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        Set<String> mappingConflicts = dynamic.addMapping("/");

        if (!mappingConflicts.isEmpty()) {
          for (String mappingConflict : mappingConflicts) {
            logger.error("Mapping conflict: " + mappingConflict);
          }
          throw new IllegalStateException(
              "The servlet cannot be mapped to '/'");
        }

//        dynamic.setMultipartConfig(webApplicationContext.getBean(MultipartConfigElement.class));
    }

    private void registerJspServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext createContext(final Class... modules) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(modules);
        return appContext;
    }

@Configuration
@Import({ ApplicationContext.class })
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // Declare "application" scope beans here, that is, beans that are not only used by the web context

}

@Configuration
@Import({ DatabaseProperties.class, JpaService.class, Log4j.class })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com....project.data.jpa" }, repositoryFactoryBeanClass  = com.nsn.nitro.project.data.jpa.repository.GenericRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class ApplicationContext {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseProperties databaseProperties;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(databaseProperties.getHibernateDriverClassName());
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(databaseProperties.getDataSourceUrl());
        dataSource.setUser(databaseProperties.getDataSourceUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(databaseProperties.getDataSourcePassword());
        dataSource.setAcquireIncrement(5);
        dataSource.setMaxStatementsPerConnection(20);
        dataSource.setMaxStatements(100);
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(2);
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws PropertyVetoException {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(databaseProperties.getHibernateDialect());
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);

        Map<String, String> jpaPropertiesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.dialect", databaseProperties.getHibernateDialect());
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932976/foreign-key-data-integrity-violation-on-oracle-x-10g
//        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "true");
//        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "false");
//        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "false");
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", databaseProperties.getHibernateHbm2ddlAuto());
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.transaction.factory_class", "org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory");
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "5");
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "20");
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "1000");
        jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "50");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.....project.data.jpa.domain");
        factoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertiesMap);
        String[] mappingsResources = new String[] {"custom/typedef.hbm.xml"};        
        factoryBean.setMappingResources(mappingsResources);
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        try {
            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        } catch (Exception x) {
            throw new RuntimeException(x);
        }
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean 
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator(){ 
      return new HibernateExceptionTranslator(); 
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
       return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

Some Maven dependencies are:

```
  <org.springframework.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
      <version>0.16.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you show us your `MockMvc` setup (config and such)?

Comment: I added the MockMvc setup, but it's pretty bare. Anything else I should display ? Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to see your actual web application context. Also, what is `RestConstants.BTS`? Is that matching your `@Controller` level `@RequestMapping`?

Comment: I added the web configuration annotations and the REST paths constants. The constants are fine, they are being used by other handlers as well. I also had a logger.debug in the multipartResolver function and it showed up in the console log.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are experiencing. Post the full stack trace. Post your test class.

Comment: I already posted the test class. Or you mean something else ? Okay, I'll post the stacktrace in a few minutes.

Comment: I'd like to see which context you load through `@ContextConfiguration`. I'd like to see your `@WebAppConfiguration`. Which Spring version are you using?

Comment: I added it on the question. Thanks !

Comment: I removed the Spring Security I had in place and the message changed a bit. It now says: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to obtain request part: json. The part is missing or multipart processing is not configured. Check for a MultipartResolver bean or if Servlet 3.0 multipart processing is enabled.

Comment: I'm running the test on Tomcat 7.

Comment: I could successfully implement and run a file upload feature using AngularJS on that controller handler. I had to make the handler parameters json and random required = false. It works just fine when called manually from my client application. But it fails when called from the test saying a parameter is not provided.

Comment: The full error message: [ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.project.rest.controller.BTSUploadController.handleFileUpload(com.project.rest.controller.BTSUploadController$JsonPojo,java.lang.String,java.util.List<org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile>)]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to obtain request part: json. The part is missing or multipart processing is not configured. Check for a MultipartResolver bean or if Servlet 3.0 multipart processing is enabled.

Comment: By the way, when manually called from the client application, the handler started working when I removed the handler parameter: ", BindingResult result) {" from the list of parameters.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same issue. I realized that I had invalid headers in my request such as

```
content-type : application/json
```

upon removing this header, the error went away.